# Very slow (~2KB/s) network file transfer of files bigger than a specific size, no matter the OS

Tags: networking, performance, ethernet

I have an `ASRock J4105B-ITX` mainboard with either Manjaro Linux or FreeNAS as OS. Both times I tried this command from another machine connected to the same network:

```
# if I have the Manjaro system running
truncate -s 184301 testfile.txt && scp ./testfile.txt manjaro@manjaro-gnome:/tmp/
# or for the FreeNAS system
truncate -s 132003 testfile.txt && scp ./testfile.txt myuser@freenas:/tmp/
```

Both times the file transfer is pretty slow, less than 2KB/s. However, when I run these very slightly modified commands, it is most of the time at ~5MB/s:

```
# if I have the Manjaro system running
truncate -s 184300 testfile.txt && scp ./testfile.txt manjaro@manjaro-gnome:/tmp/
#                ^ changed here
# or for the FreeNAS system
truncate -s 132002 testfile.txt && scp ./testfile.txt myuser@freenas:/tmp/
#                ^ changed here
```

If the size of the `testfile.txt` is smaller than these numbers it also has a high speed of around 5MB/s. However, if it is bigger or the same as in the first version it is also very slow ~2KB/s.

This issue also happens with basically all network transfers from and to this machine, slow internet, slow uploads, etc. I tried to change the network cable, didn't work either (well, the changing worked but it had no effect on the performance problem).

All other machines on the local network work fine. I tried the same experiment as described to a RaspberryPi and it didn't have any issues.

What could be the source of this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check your MTU values.

Comment: @davidgo `ip addr | grep mtu` results in `2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000` 1500 seems to be a normal value, right?

Comment: 1500 is fairly typical, yes.  Looking at https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/J4105B-ITX/index.asp#Specification your board has a realtek card. Realtek are notorious, and I generally just toss them for something else (normally with the word Intel). If thats not an option, check the nic driver module. I stumbled on   https://tuxbyte.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/ - It hints that your system might be falling back to an ultraslow incorrect driver.

Comment: Agree with the realtek comment. Go intel pro adapter, you won't be sorry with the investment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was most likey a problem with the Speedport W 724V Router. The problem affected all machines connected via ethernet. I just noticed it now because usually, I have all machines connected over WIFI. And WIFI worked. I restarted the router and it seems like the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a duplex problem.  This can happen if the interface doesn't negotiate it's speed/duplex correctly with the switch it's connected to.

If it's a 100mbit network, try specifying 100/Full instead of 100/Auto and see if that helps.

If it's a gigabit connection, try stepping the speed down to 100/Full and see if things improve.

Gigabit ethernet was supposed to fix this hassle, but I still see it, especially on some of the low-budget interface cards.  They just can't seem to negotiate in some cases for some reason.  Older 100mbit cards and switches sometimes just wouldn't agree to autonegotiate, but if you set 100/Full specifically, they would usually cooperate.